# How to place text in middle of the field

Tags: blackberry

Hi everyone I am developing a app where I need to place the text in middle of the LabelField based on the length of the text.If the text is more than the screensize it should display in multiplelines.How can I wrap the text. I am using following code

```
curCardText = tempCard.getText();
            text = new LabelField(curCardText) {
                public int getPreferredWidth() {
                    return Display.getWidth() - 100;
                }

                protected void layout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                    super.layout(getPreferredWidth(), maxHeight);
                    setExtent(getPreferredWidth(), getHeight());
                }
            };
```

and place the field in the manager using setPositionChild(), by hardcoding parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find the answer to this on the blackberry developer forum:

[Re: multilined text in LabelField or any other field.](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/multilined-text-in-LabelField-or-any-other-field/m-p/136403?query.id=287655#M15544)